# How to include deleted items in query BookshelfJS?

Tags: bookshelf.js

How to include deleted items in query BookshelfJS? I tried this query

```
User.forge().where('deleted_at', "IS NOT", null).fetchAll();
```

In the debugging output

```
select * from users where `deleted_at` is null and `deleted_at` is not null
```

Comment: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-wheres

Comment: @devius no built in function inside bookshelfjs?

Comment: Bookshelf uses Knex, so you just have to read Knex's documentation on how to use `.where()`.